# Is it possible to write a HTML file with inline css by using perl CGI.pm?

Tags: perl, cgi, perl-module

I am asked to make a form that get the width, unit, direction and a paragraph by using `CGI.pm`and forms from user. Then I need to apply width, unit and direction to the paragraph by CSS rules.

I was wondering if it is possible to write inline CSS in Perl using `CGI.pm`.

For example:

```
<p style=width:"user-width user-unit";text-align:"user-justification">
 paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Its better not to mix View(HTML,CSS) and Controller (your CGI script doing logic)

Comment: My teacher asked me to do it as a practice

Comment: If you have to do it for class, then you have to do it for class, I guess... but you're practicing a bad habit. Using CGI.pm's HTML-generating functions is generally recognized as a Bad Idea these days. Using a templating system instead (such as Template::Toolkit or Xslate) is The Right Way To Do It, at least until something even better comes along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible using `-style` parameter.

Example: `print h1({-style=>'Color: red;'},'Welcome to Hell');`

You can also create separate CSS file. Below is an example which uses separate stylesheet (style.css) and also inline CSS.

```
print start_html( -title=>'CGI with Style',
                      -style=>{-src=>'http://www.example.com/style/style.css',
                               -code=>$newStyle}
                     );
    print h1('CGI with Style'),
          p({-class=>'Tip'},
            "Better read the cascading style sheet spec before playing with this!"),
          span({-style=>'color: magenta'},
               "Look Mom, no hands!",
               p(),
               "Whooo wee!"
               );
    print end_html;
```

Source: [CGI.pm docs](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.11/CGI.pm#LIMITED_SUPPORT_FOR_CASCADING_STYLE_SHEETS)

Comment: HOW can I associate value which is given from user to css attributes?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Give some example.

Comment: print p({-style=>'width:$cgi->param('width')'});
  I want to use user input to set the width in css

Comment: It should work fine, isn't it? Make sure your `$cgi` is an object of CGI.pm module.